# Vue.js template listen to message

Tags: vue.js, events, event-handling, vuejs3

I have this template "template-main":

```
...
<template>
          ...
          <slot></slot>
          ...
</template>
...
```

Than I have my simple page that use this template

```
<template>
  <template-main>
    ...code of my page...
  </template-principal>
</template>
```

I Want to know how to send one message from my page to my template in the way that i can change a value of a variable of template-main.

I try this:
on my simple page I lauch my event with:

```
 this.$emit('message-to-template', 'hello');
```

on my template i listen to this message with:

```
<slot @message-to-template="handleMensagemRecebida"></slot>
```

but this dont work!
how to solf this?

Comment: Your page code and template-main are accessible from the same component, so just set a [prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) on the template-main element and have your page code set the prop value.  No need for events.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to emit a event from `template-main` to `your singple page`.

On `template-main` component you have to emit a event by `@click`

```js
<template>
...
     <slot>
        <button @click="$emit('message-to-template', 'hello')"></button>
    </slot>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
...
</template>



<script>
export default {
     emits: ['message-to-template'],
     props:['message']

}
</script>
```

Anh handle it like on `your single page`

```js
<template>
  <template-main message="hi" @message-to-template="handleMensagemRecebida">
    ...code of my page...
  </template-main>
</template>
```

This code is for Option API

Comment: I want to do this on the reverse way.
Send message from a [simple page] to the [template].

Comment: @aguiadouro, I have already updated my answer.